# On subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ reciprocally summable to $1$

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $\mathbb{N}$ denote the set of positive integers. If $A\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is finite, we say that $A$ is *reciprocally summable to $1$* ("rs1") if $\sum_{a\in A} \frac{1}{a} = 1$.

If $A\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is finite and $\sum_{a\in A} \frac{1}{a} < 1$, is there a finite rs1 set $A'$ with $A\subseteq A'$?

Comment: I believe yes, because for any finite extension E to bring the sum up to 1, if it over shoots, replace E by an allowed scaling factor, and try again.  There should be some algorithms in the literature on Egyptian fractions.  Gerhard "Go Sum Like An Egyptian" Paseman, 2019.08.18.

Comment: Let $N=1+\max A$ and $r=1-\sum_{a\in A}\frac{1}{a}$. Then the Main Theorem of [this paper by Croot](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9904181.pdf) implies that we can find $A'$ so that $\max A'<e^{r+o(1)}N$.

Comment: I wondered if it can be interesting to create different variants of the problem, for different definitions involving multiplicative functions $f(n)$ for the sums $\sum_{a\in A}\frac{1}{f(a)}$, for example I imagine write $f(n)=\operatorname{rad}(n)$, the product of distinct primes dividing $n>1$ (see the Wikipedia *Radical of an integer*) instead of  your $f(n)=n$ in the denominators. If you think that it has a good mathematical content, feel free to study it. I hope don't disturb.

Comment: @user142929 Thanks for your ideas - you don't disturb at all. If you want to contact me about this, use twitter.com/dominiczypen and write me a direct message

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, several algorithms for Egyptian fractions suggested by Gerhard Paseman works.

We want to represent the number $r=1-\sum_{a\in A}$ as a sum of distinct Egyptian fractions with denominators not in $A$. This may be done by many ways, for example we may use

Lemma. For any positive integers $a,n$ the number $1/a$ is representable as a sum of distinct Egyptian fractions with denominators greater than $n$.

Proof. Start with $1/a=1/a$. If it does not work (i.e., $a\leqslant n$), replace $1/a$ to $1/(a+1)+1/(a^2+a)$. After that do the same with both $1/(a+1),1/(a^2+a)$. We get four fractions which sum up to $1/a$, then eight fractions and so on. Stop when we get, say, $2^k$ fractions which are all less than $1/n$. They are all distinct (unless $a=1$, in this case use $1=1/2+1/3+1/6$), that proves Lemma. Why distinct? Assume that two of them coincide, choose the first step when this happens, say $b+1=c^2+c$ where $b,c$ were denominators on the previous step. Then the total number of steps is less than $c$, and $b=c^2+c-1$ was obtained from $c^2+c-2$, this guy in turn from $c^2+c-3$ and so on. Thus initial number $a$ was not less than $c^2$ and could not generate $c$. Lemma is proved.

Now start with the representation $r=1/N+\ldots+1/N$ for large $N>\max(A)$. Then perform the replacement algorithm: while two fractions $1/a,1/a$ in the representation are equal, replace one of them using lemma by a sum with denominators greater than anything already used. After finitely many steps we remove all repetitions.

Comment: No need to analyse a splitting algorithm (where it is not at all clear that the algorithm terminates). Fibonacci (!) proved that the greedy algorithm terminates.

Comment: @GregMartin yes, but I think we should add few words to Fibonacci's greedy algorithm termination theorem, because we have initial restrictions.

Comment: The greedy algorithm with denominators restricted to be larger than $x$ terminates by the exact same proof of Fibonacci. (Use all the smallest allowed denominators until there's a denominator that's too small to be used; then the greedy algorithm reduces the numerator of the remaining fraction by at least 1 each time.) It's still far simpler than a splitting-based algorithm—and note that your assertion that it terminates is not justified.

Comment: @GregMartin last objection is not clear for me. The number of repetitions decreases after each step, thus it obviously terminates.